# Why is navigator.getUserMedia undefined in VScode extension webview?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webcam, vscode-extensions, microphone, getusermedia

I am currently developing a videochat app for browser, which reuires the usage of navigator.getUserMedia to obtain media streams from user's webcam and microphone. I decided to extend my app to a vscode extension, for this I used a vscode webview with the iframe inside. 
Right now I get an error message that navigator.getUserMedia is undefined. So is it possible to use this function in a vscode extension?
Thank you for any help:)

Comment: IMO this is goes far beyond what vscode is for. It's a text editor and should not be misused as a general app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to use this function in a vscode extension?

It is not possible. Sorry to say.